# How to update boost::io::ios_all_saver?

Tags: c++, file, boost

I am writing a file reader class `Filereader`. It has iterators that take a reference to the file the filereader object is assigned to (`Filereader fr(filename);`). Each instance of the iterator `Filereader::output_iterator` has a members that store the state of the file when `Filereader::output_iterator::operator++()` was called last:

```
    void load_state()
    {
        ias.update(); // this method does not exist
        file_m.copyfmt(state);
        file_m.seekg(read_pointer);
        file_m.seekp(write_pointer);
    }

    void store_state()
    {
        ias.restore();
        state.copyfmt(file_m);
        read_pointer  = file_m.tellg();
        write_pointer = file_m.tellp();
    }


    std::fstream&            file_m;
    std::string              line;
    int                      line_number;
    const std::string&       file_name;
    std::ios                 state;
    decltype(file_m.tellg()) read_pointer;
    decltype(file_m.tellp()) write_pointer;
    boost::io::ios_all_saver ias{file_m};
```

The incrementation operator looks like this:

```
    output_iterator& operator++()
    {
        load_state();
        if (std::getline(file_m, line)) {
            line_number++;
        } else {
            assert_not_bad();
            line_number = -1;
        }
        store_state();
        return *this;
    }
```

The problem is that this does not quite work yet. `copyfmt` does not save the state flags, so when for instance the eof bit is being set, because one iterator reaches the end of the file, the other ierators will stop moving forward when incremented.

So then I tried to bring `boost::io::ios_all_saver` into this, but I don't understand hwo I can update the field `ias` of type `boost::io::ios_all_saver` like I do with `state` of type `std::ios`. I don't understand [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html). Is there a way to update `boost::io::ios_all_saver` like I suggest in my snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state savers are designed as RAII containers: they unconditionally free restore the state on destruction.

Your interface is incompatible with that because users might elect /not/ to restore state (`store_state`).

If you can live with restore being unconditional at destruction, you can fix it by adhering to the same design.

Comment: Hm, ok. But is there even a way to update the state stored in the state saver as I would need to when incrementing the iterator? If not, do you maybe know of a state saver other than `boost::io` than can be updated?

Comment: I now manually stored and set the fail, eof, bad and good bit. Works, but I wanted to avoid this becuase I am not sure if I am overlooking some bug potential with this.